# Comparing coordinates that are not exactly the same

Tags: c#

I have a problem. I want to compare 2 coordinates with each other, but the coordinates doesn't have to be exactly the same. It's allowed to have a maximum difference of 0,1. So I created this code:

```
public class HexagonRegistryList
{
    public int HexagonNum { get; set; }
    public float x1 { get; set; }
    public float y1 { get; set; }
    public float x2 { get; set; }
    public float y2 { get; set; }
    public float x3 { get; set; }
    public float y3 { get; set; }
    public float x4 { get; set; }
    public float y4 { get; set; }
    public float x5 { get; set; }
    public float y5 { get; set; }
    public float x6 { get; set; }
    public float y6 { get; set; }
    public int ShapeNum { get; set; }

    public HexagonRegistryList()
    {
        this.AdjacentShapeNumbers = new List<int>();
    }

    public List<int> AdjacentShapeNumbers { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<(float x, float y)> GetPoints()
    {
        yield return (x1, y1);
        yield return (x2, y2);
        yield return (x3, y3);
        yield return (x4, y4);
        yield return (x5, y5);
        yield return (x6, y6);
    }

    public struct PointComparer : IEqualityComparer<(float x, float y)>
    {
        public bool Equals((float x, float y) p1, (float x, float y) p2)
        {
            return Math.Abs(p1.x - p2.x) < 0.1f && Math.Abs(p1.y - p2.y) < 0.1f;
        }

        public int GetHashCode((float x, float y) obj)
        {
            return obj.GetHashCode();
        }
    }

    public bool IsAdjacentTo(HexagonRegistryList other)
    {
        //var isAdjacentTo = GetPoints().Intersect(other.GetPoints()).Count() >= 2;
        var isAdjacentTo = GetPoints().Intersect(other.GetPoints(), new PointComparer()).Count() >= 2;
        if (isAdjacentTo)
        {
            if (other.ShapeNum != 0)
            {
                AdjacentShapeNumbers.Add(other.ShapeNum);
            }
        }
        return isAdjacentTo;
    }
}
```

Now when it gets at this line: `var isAdjacentTo = GetPoints().Intersect(other.GetPoints(), new PointComparer()).Count() >= 2;` It returns false, what is supposed to be true. Here are the coordinates:

```
x1 = 607.5
y1 = 935.3075

x2 = 607.5
y2 = 935.3074
```

As you can see the y coordinates have a difference of 0.0001, but that shouldn't be a problem with my code. But for some reason it says that these coordinates don't match!

I am comparing hexagon sides with each other, so here is the main call I do:

```
var sharedEdges = hexagons.GetPairs().Where(t => hexagon.IsAdjacentTo(hexagons[i]));
```

I am also using this class for the comparing:

```
public static class EnumerableExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<(T first, T second)> GetPairs<T>(this IEnumerable<T> list)
    {
        return list.SelectMany((value, index) => list.Skip(index + 1),
                                (first, second) => (first, second));
    }
}
```

hexagons is a List and hexagon is just 1 hexagon in the list.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Firstly, what happens if you place a breakpoint in the `PointComparer.Equals` method.  Does the code hit that line?

Comment: Some assumptions are made, even in code written by microsoft, that a value (of difference) smaller than `0.0001f` is equal to `0`   (`if (length < 0.0001f) ....`)

Comment: `It's allowed to have a maximum difference of 0,1` this is valid as the difference is `0.0001` not `1` (or `0.1` if that comma is supposed to be a decimal)

Comment: Yes I have that, but that looks just nicer in the text. I coding I use the decimal!

Comment: Use what is accurate not what 'looks nice' otherwise it's going to harm your chances of getting helped...

Comment: @UK_Dev: Please be aware that "accurate" is culture-specific. Many cultures use comma as a decimal separator. It's entirely possible that the OP is from such a culture and may not be aware of the potential for confusion.

Comment: @UK_Dev I am sorry, but I have used the decimal in my code so, you could copy/paste it without a problem?

Comment: Whats the `>=2` for?  `Intersect` returns a collection that only contains items that match, so your expecting at least 2 matches?  If you just want to know if at least 1 point is adjacent to another this should `>=1`

Comment: Yes, because I am comparing sides of hexagons with each other. So I want to check if a side matches with another hexagon. That's why it needs to have 2 intersects

Comment: How about if you round the values in the PointComparer instead to the desired precision. (in both GetHashCode and Equals)

Comment: @Magnus: That can end up with some oddities, where two values that are close to each other round away from each other, whereas two values that are further apart round towards each other. I suspect it wouldn't be very satisfactory.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway The breakpoint doesn't hit that line!?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suspect the problem is that `Intersect` is effectively building a hash set to compare for equality. Your two "nearly equal" coordinates won't have the same hash code, so it won't even call `Equals`. You *could* implement `GetHashCode` by always returning 0, but fundamentally you've still got a big problem: your equality comparer can't implement [`IEqualityComparer<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.iequalitycomparer-1?view=netframework-4.8) as intended. An equality comparer should obey these rules for `Equals`:

- Reflexive: `Equals(x, x)` should return true - that's fine
- Symmetric: `Equals(x, y)` should return `Equals(y, x)` - that's fine too
- Transitive: if `Equals(x, y)` and `Equals(y, z)` return true, then `Equals(x, z)` should return true too - and that's *not* fine.

If you have three points, say:

- a=(0, 0)
- b=(0.09, 0)
- c=(0.18, 0) then you're saying that `a` and `b` are close, and `b` and `c` are close, but `a` and `c` are not close

Asking for *proximity* isn't the same as asking for *equality* - and you want the former.

I realize this answer doesn't show you what you should do - but it's showing you where you're going wrong. I think you'll need to change your approach entirely. It's not entirely clear to me what you want to achieve in your method, but you might want to consider finding the distances between points instead of treating them as equal.

Comment: I have added some details about what I am doing with this code at the end of my question. Can you please take a look at that!

Comment: @A.Vreeswijk: I think it's better to stick to a single question per post, to be honest. This answer is intended to concisely but completely explain where the current approach goes wrong. A question of how to implement what you want would need clearer details about the intentions, to be honest. I would note that your `IsAdjacentTo` method has a side-effect as well (adding to AdjacentShapeNumbers) which is generally a bad idea for a method that *sounds* pure, and is used in a LINQ query.

Comment: Yes okay, I get that. But then I have to wait 90 min, so can you please give me a example of what I need to do then?

Comment: @A.Vreeswijk I think you have to abandon the `Intersect` and the equality, and instead loop over the two collections of points, in that loop you could then determine the count of points that are 'close'.

Comment: @A.Vreeswijk: No - I suggest you use those 90 minutes a) trying what I've already suggested (thinking about the distances between points); b) writing a really clear question. I usually find that writing a good question from scratch takes more than 90 minutes anyway.